# Proving in/correctness of greedy algorithm to partition a set into two subsets with sums as close as possible

Tags: algorithms

> Given $n$ positive integers, we want to partition them into two sets $A$ and $B$ so that the sums $S_A$ and $S_B$ of their elements are as evenly balanced as possible, i.e., there is no other split $(A', B')$ such that $|S_{A'} - S_{B'}| < |S_A - S_B|$. We use the following greedy algorithm: sort
>   the values in decreasing order, start with empty $A$ and $B$ and always put the next value into the set with the lowest sum (choose any set if their sums are equal).
>
> Does this algorithm always produce the most balanced split? Prove it, or find a counterexample.

I think the algorithm is correct, and I understand that I'm supposed to use an "exchange argument" technique to prove this by considering an optimal solution $O = (A', B')$ and transforming it step-by-step to $O'$, $O''$, ... until I reach the solution outputted by the algorithm $S = (A, B)$, preserving optimality along the way.

I have no idea what the transformation should be, however. The obvious thing to do would be to find the first element that's mismatched between $O$ and $S$ (in $A$ but not in $A'$, or in $B$ but not in $B'$) and swap it, but that doesn't actually work in the following example:

> original set = $\{5,4,3,2,1\}$
>
> $S$ = $\{5, 2, 1\}$ and $\{4, 3\}$, $|S_A - S_B| = 1$
>
> $O$ = $\{5, 3\}$ and $\{4, 2, 1\}$, $|S_{A'} - S_{B'}| = 1$
>
> $O'$ = $\{5\}$ and $\{4, 3, 2, 1\}$, $|S_{A'} - S_{B'}| = 5$ (found and swapped $3$, did not preserve optimality)

What's a transformation that would preserve optimality here? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hint: you should be looking for a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

You want the smallest number to be fairly large, because the greedy algorithm will force the error to be no more than the smallest one.  You want the error just before the smallest is placed to be small so the error at the end is rather large and you have hope for a better solution.  This suggests having an odd number of numbers, all about the same size.  For an example, let the set be $\{6,7,8,9,10\}.$  After we place the first four we have $\{7,10\}$ and $\{8,9\}$ with equal sum and $6$ yet to place, so the error will be $6$ regardless of where we place it.  If we are smart, we separate them into $\{9,10\}$ and $\{6,7,8\}$ with an error of only $2$.